# How to input this request into the body of a Postman request?

Tags: json, swagger, postman

How to send the following request with the body of a Postman request?

```
{
   Consumer:
 {
ConsumerId:
 }
 PersonUnderCare
 {
 Age: integer
 Gender:     string
 RelationId: integer
 RelationOther: string
 ProductInUseId: integer
 ProductInUseOther: string
 Condition: 
 ConditionOther: string
 }
 }
```

Comment: You want to send this in your `POST` command parameters?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a JSON validator to make sure you have valid json, then put it in the body with the "raw" option. Select "body", "raw", and then instead of plain text, select JSON from the drop down menu.

I took some liberties with the code you provided, but I believe the correct JSON format would look something like this

```
{
    "Consumer": {
        "ConsumerId": {
            "PersonUnderCare": [{
                "Age": 9,
                "Gender": "gender",
                "RelationId": "id",
                "RelationOther": "string",
                "ProductInUseId": 9,
                "ProductInUseOther": "string",
                "Condition": "string",
                "ConditionOther": "string"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I used 
[JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate the JSON